# Response body is of type string, how do I change it to JSON object

Tags: json, amazon-s3, apache-camel, apache-camel-aws

The body of my post request to rest camel component is not in the form of a json. Hence I am not able to extract the key-value pairs. How do I convert body into json?
I sent a json object of this type

```
{
    "filename": "hello.txt",
    "bucketName": "cameltry",
    "accessKey":  "key",
    "secretKey": "key",
    "region" : "us-east-1"
}
```

I have to use this json data to download a file from AWS S3. The corresponding route in camel is:

```
public static class HelloRoute extends RouteBuilder {
       
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            rest("/")
                .post("file-from-s3")
                    .route()
                    .setHeader(AWS2S3Constants.KEY, constant($body[filename]))
                    .toD("aws2-s3://${body[bucketName]}?accessKey=${body[accessKey]}&secretKey=${body[secretKey]}&region=${body[region]}&operation=getObject")
                    .to("file:/tmp/")
                    .endRest();
        }
```

Here `$body[filename]` turns out to be null as `$body` is not a json object. How do I convert it into a json object?

Answer (score 0):

You can do .post("file-from-s3").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)

Comment: I tried this before but it was giving me an error -> ```Cannot bind to json as message body is not json compatible.```

Comment: Can you provide your `restConfiguration` clause?

Comment: I have not added a ```restConfiguration``` clause

Comment: can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62861916/how-to-view-messages-from-an-sqs-queue-using-apache-camel

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library for JSON parsing if the `bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)` answer suggested above doesn't work for you.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard json xstream library, or use one of the other options at https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/json.html to marshal it into a POJO.

```
public static class HelloRoute extends RouteBuilder {
   
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        rest("/")
            .post("file-from-s3")
                .route()
                .marshal().json()
                .setHeader(AWS2S3Constants.KEY, constant($body[filename]))
                .toD("aws2-s3://${body[bucketName]}?accessKey=${body[accessKey]}&secretKey=${body[secretKey]}&region=${body[region]}&operation=getObject")
                .to("file:/tmp/")
                .endRest();
    }
```