# How to view messages from an sqs queue using Apache camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, amazon-sqs

I have an apache camel rest api that should view the messages in my sqs queue. The code is like so ->

```
.post("sqs-view-message")
.route()
.from("aws2-sqs://queueName?accessKey=insert&secretKey=insert&region=us-east-1)
.log("${body}")
.endRest();
```

But when I am logging the `$body` it is coming empty even though I have messages in my queue. Is this not the correct way to fetch messages from an AWS sqs queue?

Comment: Can you replace the "from" with "pollEnrich"? `.pollEnrich(queuename)`

Comment: Didn't you miss " at the end of  the url in from?

Comment: @PooryaHosseini that is just a typo while posting the question

Comment: @SneharghyaPathak ```.pollEnrich``` worked thanks, when do I use this? is it applicable for all ```from``` statements?

Comment: `pollEnrich` assumes the incoming Exchange is a simple trigger that tells Camel to ignore the contents of the incoming message and look for data elsewhere.

Comment: What you did initially was semantically incorrect as the route is already getting an exchange from the post endpoint, so `from` cannot be used here.

Comment: @SneharghyaPathak  I can't use ```pollEnrich``` with a dynamic functionality? I am getting the URL from a process and I am setting that as my body. When I am doing ```.pollEnrich("aws2-sqs://${body}")``` it is giving an error

Comment: It is given here that we can use dynamic uri https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/eips/pollEnrich-eip.html#_using_dynamic_uris

so basically my process sets the body as the URL and I want to make a request using that. Reding the docs I was trying to do something like this ```.pollEnrich().simple("aws2-sqs://${bodyl}")``` but this is just giving ```poll Enrich``` as output.

Comment: What error are you getting for `.pollEnrich().simple("aws2-sqs://${body}")`?

Comment: never mind its working

Comment: @SneharghyaPathak can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62942034/how-to-create-an-iam-user-using-apache-camel

Comment: @PooryaHosseini can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62942034/how-to-create-an-iam-user-using-apache-camel

Comment: @SneharghyaPathak can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63101656/retrieve-item-from-dynamodb-using-apache-camel

Comment: @PooryaHosseini can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63101656/retrieve-item-from-dynamodb-using-apache-camel