# How to send batch message to a sqs queue using apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, amazon-sqs

I have a rest api in apache camel. I wrote a code like so to send a batch message to sqs using apache camel following their documentation.

```
 .post("sqs-send-batch-message")
                    .route()
                    .process(new Processor(){
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            String message = "Hello World";
                            exchange.getIn().setBody(message);
                        }
                        
                    })
                    .to("aws2-sqs://queueName?accessKey=insert&secretKey=insert&region=us-east-1&operation=sendBatchMessage")
                    .endRest()
```

But this is returning a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. This is the way it was given in their documentation. Is there some other way to send batch message to sqs using apache camel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reported in the documentation you need to pass an iterable as body. Here is an integration test: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-aws2-sqs/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/aws2/sqs/integration/SqsProducerBatchSendIntegrationTest.java

Alternatively you can pass a SendBatchRequest Pojo as body directly: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-aws2-sqs/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/aws2/sqs/Sqs2Producer.java#L107

This is stated in the documentation: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/aws2-sqs-component.html#_send_batch_message

I don't know where you read about that way of send batch message. Can you please report an issue if the documentation is somewhere incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: thanks, can you look at this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62861916/how-to-view-messages-from-an-sqs-queue-using-apache-camel

Comment: can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62942034/how-to-create-an-iam-user-using-apache-camel