# How to create an IAM User using apache camel?

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel, amazon-iam

I have a camel rest api. I was trying to create an IAM User using apache camel framework. The code is like so ->

```
.post("iam-create-user")
   .route()
   .process(new Processor(){
      @Override
      public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
         exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelAwsIAMUsername", "new-user");
      })
      .to("aws2-iam://current-user?accessKey=insert&secretKey=insert&operation=createUser")

   .endRest();
```

I am getting this error `java.lang.NullPointerException: null`.  What is the correct way of doing this? It shows in the camel docs to use a URL like so `to("aws2-iam://test?iamClient=#amazonIAMClient&operation=createUser")`. What do we put as `iamClient`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iamClient reported in the example (#amazonIAMClient) is an instance of IAMClient you'll need to put in the Camel registry with a bind name  amazonIAMClient.

I think you need to specify region as aws-global for this particular component.

Maybe add the full stack trace of your error.

Comment: thanks, can you look at this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62985926/how-to-update-a-lambda-function-using-apache-camel