# How to update a lambda function using apache camel?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, apache-camel

I hava a camel rest api which is supposed to update my existing function in aws lambda. The code is like so ->

```
.post("lambda-update-function")
   .route()
   .process(new Processor(){

      @Override
      public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
      exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelAwsLambdaS3Bucket", "bucketName");
      exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelAwsLambdaS3Key", "aws1.zip");
      }
    })
   .to("aws2-lambda://functionName?accessKey=insert&secretKey=insert&region=us-east-1&operation=updateFunction")
   .endRest();
```

The updated version of the zip file is in a S3 bucket hence I have used those headers. When I hit a request on that route I get an error `Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.model.InvalidParameterValueException: Please provide a source for function code. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 39d05e32-a862-41fb-ab12-a6cdf0d5e516, Extended Request ID: null)`.

Comment: Can you try by adding something to the exchange Body?

Comment: Nope that didn't work, In the lambda2producer file, there is a condition inside the update function code ```if (ObjectHelper.isEmpty(exchange.getIn().getBody()) && (ObjectHelper.isEmpty(exchange.getIn().getHeader(Lambda2Constants.S3_BUCKET))
                                                                         && ObjectHelper.isEmpty(exchange.getIn().getHeader(Lambda2Constants.S3_KEY)))) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("At least S3 bucket/S3 key or zip file must be specified");    }``` Should this be separated using ``||`` since atleast is the keyword