# Retrieve item from DynamoDB using apache camel

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-camel, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to use the apache camel aws2 DynamoDB component to retrieve an item. In the docs, it is given that we can use an operation `getItem` in order to achieve this. I wrote a code like so ->

```
.post("dynamodb-get-item")
    .route()
    .process(new Processor(){
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            Map<String, AttributeValue> key = new HashMap();
            key.put("LastName", AttributeValue.builder().s("Smith").build());
            exchange.getIn().setHeader(Ddb2Constants.KEY, key);
            exchange.getIn().setHeader(Ddb2Constants.ATTRIBUTE_NAMES, key.keySet());
        }        
    })
    .toD("aws2-ddb://user?accessKey=insert&secretKey=insert&region=us-east-1&operation=getItem")
    .process(new Processor(){
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            Map<String, AttributeValue> response =  (Map<String, AttributeValue>) exchange.getIn().getHeader(Ddb2Constants.ATTRIBUTES);
            exchange.getIn().setBody(response);
        }
    })
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .endRest();
```

The name of the DynamoDb table is `user` and the key is `LastName`. This code executes successfully and returns this response `{LastName=AttributeValue(S=Smith, SS=[], NS=[], BS=[], M={}, L=[])}`. This response has only the attribute `LastName`. This doesn't return the attribute `FirstName` and `Age` which is also part of this item. If I use the aws cli with this command `aws dynamodb get-item --table-name user --key '{"LastName": {"S": "Smith"}}'` I get the correct response like so ->

```
{
    "Item": {
        "LastName": {
            "S": "Smith"
        }, 
        "Age": {
            "N": "22"
        }, 
        "FirstName": {
            "S": "Will"
        }
    }
}
```

How to get the full response like above using the `getItem` producer operation of apache camel aws2 DynamoDb component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used header `Ddb2Constants.ATTRIBUTE_NAMES` which causes filtering of response attributes.

From [AWS DynamoDB Component documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/aws-ddb-component.html):

> `CamelAwsDdbAttributeNames` - If attribute names are not specified then all attributes will be returned.

So just remove the line `exchange.getIn().setHeader(Ddb2Constants.ATTRIBUTE_NAMES, key.keySet());` and you will get full response.

Comment: @Bedia this returns a Map<String, AttributeValue>, this is the response -> ```{FirstName=AttributeValue(S=Willt, SS=[], NS=[], BS=[], M={}, L=[]), LastName=AttributeValue(S=Smith, SS=[], NS=[], BS=[], M={}, L=[]), Age=AttributeValue(N=22, SS=[], NS=[], BS=[], M={}, L=[])}```. How do I change it to something like -> 
```{
   "FirstName" :{ "S" : " Will"},
   "LastName" : {"S" : "Smith"},
   "Age" : {"N" : 22}
}```
I can extract the keys from the map but how do I extract the ```AttributeValue``` like above?

Comment: Remove `.convertBodyTo(String.class)`. Then convert the `Map<String, AttributeValue>` in your processor to some json serializable structure. Eg with [ItemUtils](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/ItemUtils.html). `exchange.getIn().setBody(ItemUtils.toItem( exchange.getIn().getHeader(Ddb2Constants.ATTRIBUTES, Map.class)).asMap())`

Comment: Can you pls look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124977/how-to-scan-a-dynamodb-table-using-apache-camel