# How to scan a dynamodb table using apache camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, amazon-dynamodb

I have a camel rest api which scans a DynamoDb table. The code is like so ->

```
.post("dynamodb-scan-table")
   .route()
  .toD("aws2-ddb://user?accessKey=insert&secretKey=insert&region=us-east-1&operation=Scan")
  .endRest();
```

This returns all the items in my table. My problem is how to scan the table based on a certain condition. In the camel [docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/aws2-ddb-component.html), it is given that there is a header `CamelAwsDdbScanFilter` which is of the type `Map<String, Condition>`  needs to be set in order to achieve the solution for my problem. I have a table of users and suppose I want to retrieve all the users with `FirsName = Will`. How do I implement the  `Map<String, Condition>` in order to achieve this? Basically I am not sure what to put in the `Condition` of the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find example usage in [ScanCommandTest](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-aws-ddb/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/aws/ddb/ScanCommandTest.java#L55).

For condition `FirstName` eq `Will` the filter could be something like:

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader(DdbConstants.SCAN_FILTER, new HashMap<String, Condition>(){{
    put("FirsName", new Condition()
            .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
            .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS("Will")));
}});
```

Comment: can you look at this ques https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63136841/how-to-put-a-map-as-attribute-value-in-dynamodb-using-apache-camel