# How to put a map as attribute value in DynamoDb using apache camel?

Tags: apache-camel, amazon-dynamodb

I want to put a map like so `"M": {"Name": {"S": "Joe"}, "Age": {"N": "35"}}` using the `PutItem` opearation of apache camel. The code would be something like this ->

```
.post("dynamodb-put-item")
    .route()
    .process(new Processor(){
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            Map<String, AttributeValue> key = new HashMap();
            key.put("M", AttributeValue.builder().m(//Something needs to be added here).build());
            exchange.getIn().setHeader(Ddb2Constants.ITEM, key);
            exchange.getIn().setHeader(Ddb2Constants.RETURN_VALUES, "ALL_OLD");

        }
        
    })
    .toD("aws2-ddb://user?accessKey=insert&secretKey=insert&region=us-east-1&operation=PutItem")
    .endRest();
```

`{"Name": {"S": "Joe"}` and `"Age": {"N": "35"}}` are individually a `Map<String, Attribute value>`. For this example I can manually hard code it by creating one more map for `{"Name": {"S": "Joe"}` and `"Age": {"N": "35"}}`. But I am looking for a general solution because a map can be of type string, boolean , **map**, **list** etc. How to make a general thing which will handle all the possible cases of a map?

Comment: Where map values come from?

Comment: It will come as a json input to the ```dynamodb-put-item``` route. So it will be a JSONObject like ```{"M": {"Name": {"S": "Joe"}, "Age": {"N": "35"}}```. Now I have to change this json object to Map<String, Attributevalue>.